# JavaFX with Quartz scheduler

Tags: java, javafx, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to create an application that will create popups at certain times, using JavaFX and Quartz scheduler API.
I have got it so that a JavaFX GUI creates the events, adds them into a Quartz scheduler, and runs the job at the correct time. However, I can't parse non-primitives into a Quartz job, so I can't get my job.class to interact with the current instance of stage/controller I can't make the job.class interact with the current JavaFX stage. And I can't just launch a new JavaFX stage because JavaFX does not allow multiple launches.
Here is my current job scheduling:

```
for (Map.Entry<Date,ScheduleBlock> set : jobs.entrySet()) {
    if (set.getKey().before(new Date())) {
        System.out.println("job already expired");
    } else {

        JobDetail jd = JobBuilder.newJob(TimedJob.class)
                .withIdentity(set.getValue().toString())
                .build();

        SimpleTrigger t = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger()
                .startAt(set.getKey())
                .withIdentity(set.getValue().toString())
                .build();
        s.scheduleJob(jd, t);
    }
}
```

Where `jobs` is a treemap of Date with my custom data object ScheduleBlock.
Here is my job.class:

```
public class TimedJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        Notification notification = new Notification();
        try {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    notification.main(null);
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using `runlater` because that's what a different answer said might work for someone else's similar issue.
And finally here is my Notification class

```
public class Notification extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("notification start");
        Parent root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("notification.fxml"));
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(root1);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("notification main");
        launch();
    }
}
```

When the job is activated I get this error:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called on the JavaFX Application Thread

Comment: `launch()` can only be called once, when the entire application starts up. It will also block until the application exits. Just launch an application in the usual way, do any Quartz-related initialization in the `init()` method, and show a new stage when you need. The `start()` method can be empty if there's nothing to be shown at actual startup.

Comment: I can't do the quartz initialise in init because the schedule is dependent on what the user does within the application i.e. creating tasks and adding them to the day's schedule. I suppose I could have seperate set up and scheduling applications but that's not ideal

Comment: I don't know Quartz, but presumably you can show a config screen in `start`, then initialize Quartz when the user interacts with it, or update the Quartz configuration once the user has provided data, etc. Anyway, the point is that `launch` is called once, when the application is launched. You can't call it again (see the [Javadocs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#launch(java.lang.String...))